# BJT switches pair

Tags: transistors, switches

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPHKYW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to do something like this: V1 is a variable (0 to 3.3V) voltage source, so above some value like 0.7 ~ 1.0 V I want Q1 as a closed switch, providing I1 to my load and Q2 as open switch. When V1 goes down, then Q2 is closed and Q1 is open. I1 is controlled by V1 too, when V1 = 3.3V then I1 = 15mA(maximum value).
So, how can I correctly put my BJT's on cutoff and saturation region? I prefer to use BJT's due to low V1 levels, and want to do this by using just one control signal (V1). If necessary I can add more BJT's or change NPN's or PNP's... This is just my first NPN and PNP combination idea. 
Ps. Sorry for my bad english.

[image: This figure is what I want to do]

Comment: This is probably **not** going to work, but we need to know the value of the load resistor or at least the maximum voltage you expect to see across it. If that voltage is very small the circuit will work better, but the transistors will not act like the ideal switches you have drawn.

Comment: Well, initially I'm making a 12V circuit, varying load between 100R to 500R... But, my objective is make a 90V circuit, so load will varying load up to 100k...

Comment: 15mA * 100K is 1.5kV, so 90V isn't going to cut it.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with this simulation (click on Run Time Domain Simulation). The 2N5551 is a very old transistor, it just happens to be one that's provided as a model (and is capable of 100V), you could use something newer. If your electrode capacitance is very much higher than 100pF you may have to add some series resistance to keep within the BJTs Safe Operating Area curve.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foPo7i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]